# 3 Monitors not working on kubuntu 21.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, displayport

I want to have a setup with 3 monitors.

I have a DELL precision T1650 with 32 GB RAM and + 1TB SSD.

For display, I have 2 Phillips (1080P: 1920x1080) and one BenQ monitors(1080P: 1920x1080). The 2 Phillips are connected with 2 Display-port -> HDMI (display on computer and HDMI on screen). The BenQ is connected with vga -> vga.

On my config panel, all of them are recognized correctly.

They are not working all together iat the same time.

Only 2 are working.

When I disconnect one the 2 other start working.

When I restart my computer all show together. After login I loose one. When  I go to config, it just shows as disable.

How Can I fix so that after login all 3 monitors still work?

Feel free to ask any questions if there is some info missing on my questions.

Thanks.

Here is lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C216 Series Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Comment: Which graphics card? If Nvidia are the the drivers installed?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't know. How to fine out ?

Comment: As always, with `lspci`.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I edited

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e3-1200v3-vol-1-datasheet.pdf It does say 3 monitors are supported but at different max resolutions, different configurations and even the type of RAM does make a difference. Check table 7 and 8. Yes, confusing... I suggest checking the Dell's manual about it instead.